# passing parameters to a swf via Loader

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, loader, flashvars

I have a swf (child.swf) that I wish to load into another (parent.swf). I wish to pass a parameter to child.swf through the loader I am using. **Note that I am not trying to pass FlashVars that parent.swf already has**, but rather I am trying to simply load a swf through another swf with custom arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the child swf, write a function (init in the code below) to receive any params. When the Loader signals Event.COMPLETE, call the function from parent.swf as follows:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("child.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler);
loader.load(request);

function loadHandler(event:Event):void
{
   var childSwf:Object = event.target.content;
   childSwf.init( PARAMS );
}
```

Comment: i spent 6 hours loading it wrong based on all the other incorrect methods of a loading an remote swf. you sir just saved me 10 years off my life.

Comment: i don't know why but for my case, the 'event.target.content' is always instance of 'mx_managers_SystemManager'

Comment: It would be useful to see what the code for the child swf too?