# Passing params to an external swf via loader

Tags: xml, actionscript, flash

I have a map of the US acquired from [here](http://www.backspace.com/mapapp/) (called U.S. Map). I am currently generating XML from inside an ActionScript file, and would then like to display this map using my generated XML as the argument. According to [this](http://www.backspace.com/mapapp/configure.html#embed), to do this in html would require the following declaration:

```
world.swf?data_file=pathname/filename.xml
```

How can I replicate this behavior using the Loader from ActionScript? Right now I have:

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
var url:String = "us/us.swf?data_file=senate.xml";
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
ldr.load(urlReq);
addChild(ldr);
```

I'd like to note that I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426143/passing-paramaters-to-a-swf-via-loader). However, it doesn't seem to be able to solve my problem, since I can't edit the US Map swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is URLVariables:

```
var variables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.data_file = "senate.xml";
urlReq.data = variables;
```

Comment: Right you are! Many thanks - I'd been scouring the internet trying to find the answer, but I don't think I was phrasing the question correctly. :)